# Validate a Textbox through a Javascript CheckBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox, textbox

I am trying to validate a TextBox through a CheckBox ... The idea is the following, when the user unchecks the CheckBox (false) the field is not mandatory, but when he has the CheckBox marked (true) he has to enter the text, if he does not, I must send him a message on the screen ... I'm not sure how to do this ... any help for me?

[image: Screenshot]

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            $("#idcheckproveedor").change(function(){
                var st = this.checked;
                if (st) {
                    $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else {
                    $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                });
            });

    </script>

     <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Proveedor</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkproveedor" id="idcheckproveedor" checked="checked" value="true"/>
                        @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtSearch" })
                   </div>
```

Comment: Dont forget to also validate the information on the server side !
As any JS validation is easy to bypass !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
$(function (){
  var st = $("#idcheckproveedor").attr('checked');
  $("#idcheckproveedor").change(function(){
    st = this.checked;
    if (st) {
        $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#txtSearch").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    });
    $("#mybtn").click(function(){
      if(st && ($("#txtSearch").val() == "" || $("#txtSearch").val() == null)){
        alert("Please enter text");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label>Proveedor</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkproveedor" id="idcheckproveedor" checked="checked" value="true"/>
  <input type="text" id="txtSearch"/>
</div>
<button id="mybtn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click','.btn-submit',function(){
    
      var checked = $('#checked_indicator').is(':checked');
      var validate = true;
      var field = $('#field_only').val();
    
      if(checked){
          if(field == ''){
            validate =false;
          }
      }
      
      if(validate){
       //code here for field is not required
          alert('Your field: '+field);
          
      }else{
         
          //code here for field is required
          alert('Field is Required');
      }
    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_test">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checked_indicator"  />
  <input type="field" id="field_only" />
  <button type="button" class="btn-submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.